# Check if a class is a dataclass in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

How can I check if a class is a `dataclass` in Python?

I found out that I can check the existance of `__dataclass_fields__` and `__dataclass_params__` attributes, but I'd love to find a more elegant way to do this.

I'd expect using something like `inspect.isclass` function. Maybe something like `inspect.isdataclass`, for example.

Does Python have something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 58):

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.is_dataclass)

```py
import dataclasses
dataclasses.is_dataclass(something)
```

As mentioned by @Arne internally it simply checks `hasattr(something, '__dataclass_fields__')`, but I'd recommend to not rely on this attribute and directly use `is_dataclass`.

Why you should not rely on `__dataclass_fields__`:

- This attribute is not a public API: it's not mentioned anywhere in the docs.
- It's an implementation detail, and so it's not guaranteed to work in other python implementations. But besides `cPython` nothing seems to support Python3.7 yet (as of May 2019). At least Jython, IronPython and PyPy do not support it, so it's hard to tell if they will be using  the same attribute or not

Everything else including differences between checking for dataclass type and dataclass instance is in the docs of `is_dataclass` method:

```py
# (from the docs)
def is_dataclass_instance(obj):
    return is_dataclass(obj) and not isinstance(obj, type)
```

Comment: Note that all `is_dataclass` does under the hood is [checking for `__dataclass_fields__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0a834c18cdafa5447d4436878e64aa7a4e4dc817/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1012-L1020).

Comment: It has been exposed in python 3.83 API https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.is_dataclass

Answer (score 5):

Extending upon the answer above, the following illustrates the usage of `is_dataclass()`:

**Remember**: The parameter passed to `is_dataclass()` can be a dataclass or an instance of the dataclass, to return `True` from the method call.

```
In [1]: from dataclasses import dataclass

In [2]: @dataclass
   ...: class Bio:
   ...:     name: str
   ...:     age: int
   ...:     height: float
   ...:

In [3]: from dataclasses import is_dataclass

In [4]: is_dataclass(Bio)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: b = Bio('John', 25, 6.5)

In [6]: is_dataclass(b)
Out[6]: True
```

To check whether, `b` is an instance of the dataclass and not a dataclass itself:

```
In [7]: is_dataclass(b) and not isinstance(b, type)
Out[7]: True
```

`Bio` is a dataclass, so the following expression evaluates to `False`:

```
In [8]: is_dataclass(Bio) and not isinstance(Bio, type)
Out[8]: False
```

Lets check for a regular class:

```
In [9]: class Car:
   ...:     def __init__(self, name, color):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:         self.color = color
   ...:
```

We know `Car` is not a dataclass:

```
In [10]: is_dataclass(Car)
Out[10]: False

In [11]: c = Car('Mustang', 'Blue')
```

Neither an instance of `Car` is a dataclass instance:

```
In [12]: is_dataclass(c)
Out[12]: False
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd prefer checking if it's a class or an instance using `inspect.isclass` over `isinstance(b, type)`, but it actually does the same.

Comment: Do you want to add a check for a non-dataclass that has an attribute called `__dataclass_fields__`? =D